# Kendo UI drop down list not working inside kendoWindow

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I'm using kendoWindow in Kendo UI for adding an element to my data table in Kendo UI. 
I'm using dropdownlist for selecting the user role from a set of user roles inside it. But when I use dropdownlist inside a Kendo UI kendoWindow, I'm getting it as a textbox instead of dropdownlist. 
But when I use the same dropdownlist outside the popup windo it works as if I expected.
What is to be done in order to obtain the dropdown list inside kendoWindow?

I have attached the code here with.

In html page.

```
<div id="AddUserPopupTemplate">
    <form class="form-horizontal custom-form" role="form">
        <div class="row">
             <input data-option-label=" " data-value-primitive="true" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="UserRole" data-value-field="RoleId" data-bind="source: UserRoleSelected" />
        </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Inside the controller.

```
AddNewUser: function () {
        var myWindow = $("#AddUserPopupTemplate");

        myWindow.kendoWindow({
            width: "800px",
            title: "Add User",
            visible: false,
            actions: [
                "Pin",
                "Minimize",
                "Maximize",
                "Close"
            ],
            close: onClose
        }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();

        function onClose() {

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            myWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
        });

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using data attribute initialization, you need to force kendo to initialize it in the window's [`open`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events-open) event with [`kendo.init()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-init):

```
open: function() {
    kendo.init(myWindow);
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ineWI)

More here: [The Difference Between kendo.bind And kendo.init](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/the-difference-between-kendo.bind-and-kendo.init).